# Adding translation files to a child theme

Tags: child-theme, localization, textdomain

I am building a website with WordPress and I am using the Generatepress theme. However:

- I need to add functions, so I created a child theme.
- Generatepress is not available in a language I need (Slovak), so I have to translate it myself.

I took an existing language file, modified it with Poedit and put `sk_SK.mo` into a `languages` directory of my child theme directory. It didn't work, so after googling, I added this to the child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function generatepress_extended_locale() {
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'generatepress', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'generatepress_extended_locale' );
```

However, my website still appears in English.

Interestingly, if I replace the text domain with something else and use the same text domain in a template of my child theme, it works, which means that my `.mo` file and its location are fine. But I would like to translate the strings of the parent them and I really don't know why it doesn't work. So I would be really glad if someone could help me.

---

Okay, I kinda found a solution (it's probably dirty but it works). I copied the entire `generate_setup()` function (the one that uses `load_theme_textdomain()`) from the parent theme's `functions.php` into the to the child theme's `functions.php` and added this line:

```
load_child_theme_textdomain( 'generatepress', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
```

I guess the problem comes from the fact that `load_theme_textdomain()` was originally called after `load_child_theme_textdomain()` with the same text domain and somehow overrided it.

Comment: in your theme's functions.php file add this `add_action('init',function(){  echo get_locale(); exit; }); ` it should be `sk_SK` to translate strings to Slovak .

Comment: It displays `sk_SK`.

Comment: what is language's  `.mo` and `.po` file name in your `language` folder ? try to rename `generatepress-sk_SK.mo` and `generatepress-sk_SK.po`

Comment: They are named `sk_SK.po` and `sk_SK.mo`. I renamed them as you said but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, where did you added this code in child  or parent  theme? which is in your question ?

Comment: To the child theme (`generatepress-extended/functions.php`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49362/discussion-between-govind-kumar-and-mutre).